# Made carrousel responsive in all devices

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I can't fix my carousel images for any devices. Here is my code:

```css
div.c-wrapper {
  height: 406px;
  width: 940px;
  /* use this, or not */
  margin: auto;
}

.img-responsive {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="c-wrapper">
      <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
            <img src="Images/carrousel11.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="Images/carrousel5.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="Images/carrousel6.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="icon-prev"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
          <span class="icon-next"></span>
        </a>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you guys if can help me out!

Comment: Have you considered using a library like Slick Slider to achieve this? http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: I agree with @jeanpier_re, Slick is great slider library. Responsive out-of-the-box with a lot of options and the ability to adjust your slider for specified breakpoints - don't reinvent the wheel if you don't have to!

Comment: tnkx, could you explain it into my code, what need to change?

Comment: There are demos on http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/. You simply need to include the JavaScript file in the head of your html document then call slick() on your element either with jQuery or with plain JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I'd highly recommend using a library like Slick, the exercise of creating a slider from scratch is a worth while one to consider, if for no other reason than to better understand web technologies.

Here are a few things to consider. In order to make a proper **carousel** you'll want to use JavaScript to manage the `click` events for *next*, *previous* and clicking on the indicators. You had a number of issues with your mark up and CSS that I've done my best to match what I believe was your original intention but if anything is off let me know and we can refine from here.

### Hide the inactive image

In order to give the appearance of sliding you need to hide all but the one active slides. Then on click you simply hide the active item by remove the `.active` class then add that class to the next element - in this case by stepping through your `data-slide-to` attribute.

### Positioning

The best way that I've found to position your previous and next buttons is to use `position: absolute`. In order for this to work you need to have a relatively positioned container around it. I did this on `.carousel`.

### Extraneous markup

I didn't remove all of the unneccessary markup but you'll find that several of the divs in your example are not neccessary especially at the top level. I left those in just in case you had some other reason for that.

### Images

Quick tip, if you're going to use relative images in your SO posts, try to swap those for [Placehold.it](https://placehold.it) images as they won't render on SO.

```css
.carousel-wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}


.carousel-wrapper:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.carousel {
  position: relative;
}

.left, .right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}

.left {
  left: -50px;
}

.right {
  right: -50px;
}

.img-responsive {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.carousel-indicators {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.carousel-indicators li {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 0 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.item {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-wrapper">
      <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/500x250" class="item active img-responsive" alt="">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/500x250" class="item img-responsive" alt="">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/500x250" class="item img-responsive" alt="">
        </div>

        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="icon-prev">Prev</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
          <span class="icon-next">Next</span>
        </a>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```